# I am trying to find groups name associated with a particular user in django

Tags: django

I am facing these error

```
l = request.user.groups.values_list('name',flat=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'request' is not defined
```

Comment: Too little to go on, can you provide more details?

Comment: I am working on a web app  in django. and I am new in django.I have made a user and attached it with multiple group in django. Now what i want is to list all the no of group associated with that user.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: yes , by doing lots of looping .. first I made a list of all group.. then find whether my user is associated with that grp or not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NameError: name 'request' is not defined

Seems you're using a variable `request` that's not defined,
`request` can come for example from a view, e.g.

```
from django.views.generic import View

class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        # here you can use the request object
        user = request.user
        user.groups... # do something with the user groups
```

> I am trying to find groups name associated with a particular user in django

You can also work on the user directly without any `HttpRequest` object

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

user = User.objects.get(username='ashish')
user.groups... # do something with the user groups
```

Comment: Thanks bakkal .. finally got the expected result from this method.